# creating array of text files with FPS

Tags: arrays, file, variables, text, freepascal

Is it possible that FPS program read user input and then creates a file with a name of that input and that read another input and so on and on..?

I have tried to create array of text file but got some problems.

First of all an error occurred that (some) access was denied and secondly, how to create a result file where variable is in the middle of the text file name (I've tried assign (Df,'rezult',i,'.txt'); i - here is changing variable, but in this way program does not work.

P.S. Sorry for my English language skills...

This is what I have tried:

```
    program testing;
var
    Df : text;
    i:integer;
    SomeUserInput:integer;        
begin
for i:=1 to 10 do
 begin
 Assign(Df,'rez.txt'); Rewrite(Df);
 Read(SomeUserInput);
 WriteLn(Df,'some words + ',SomeUserInput);
 Close(Df);
 end;
Readln;
end.
```

(fixed the problem that first comment suggest, but now only last thing is written in my file, I wish to create 10 or more files)

Comment: Well I can see one obvious problem. Your loop goes from 1 to 1000, while your array goes from 1 to 100. So starting at the 101th element, you are susceptible to access violation errors. Also, you can reuse variables, so you don't need an array if you are going to be closing the file immediately after. You can just keep reusing the same one :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to number the filename with your loop var.
This should work:

```
program testing;
Uses
  SysUtils;
var
  Df : text;
  i:integer;
  SomeUserInput:integer;        
begin
  for i:=1 to 10 do
  begin
    Assign(Df,'rez'+IntToStr(i)+'.txt'); 
    Rewrite(Df);
    ReadLn(SomeUserInput);
    WriteLn(Df,'some words + ',SomeUserInput);
    Close(Df);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: @user2352065, did this answer solve your problem? If so, read [`faq#howtoask`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) to learn how to accept an answer.

Comment: Inttostr is not Pascal but Delphi. inttostr in unit system is even rarer, and I assume something of later Delphi's even. Even on FPC you have to import sysutils